# Creating another layer class for animation

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Having a main class , i want to add some other layer to with , when that layer do some animation, problem starts when i need a few copies of that layer at the same time.
For example, i have a layer which do explosion animation , on top of main current layer .
If every time i use it , i will make a copy of it(instance allocation), i will have to release that copy sometime, but i **cant** do this :

```
explotionLayer *instance=[[explotion alloc]init];
[instance someFunction ];
[instance release];
```

because the `someFunction` takes time,and when it ends, some other function from that `instance` is being performed- hence that instance can't be released before .

How can i create many instances at the same time(during a game), and somehow manage how to release them at the right time-only when they done animation,and all other task .

**I know i can callback from that instance to a function in the main layer to release it- but this is NOT a good robust way .**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
[instance autorelease];
```

No, screw that.             You should really be [using ARC](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2012/04/enabling-arc-cocos2d-project-howto-stepbystep-tutorialguide/). You won't even have to consider issues like that anymore, and you'll have fewer leaks.

Besides if instance is added to the node hierarchy, cocos2d is retaining it anyway.

Comment: but cocos2d gives so many errors when enabling arc..(v2.0). i have seen your guide, so many steps to correct such simple thing..

Answer (score 0):

Please use Automatic Referencing Count (ARC). All you need to do is to define the correct properties on instance variables and migrate to ARC. Framework will take care of memory handling for you.